# combining all elements of one single column to a single long string

Tags: python

I am calling a column from a CSV file I want to combine all char of that column as one string:

```
import glob
import os
folder_path = 'C:\\Users\\mystuff'  # path
for name in glob.glob(folder_path + '\*.csv'):
    input = open(name)
    filename = os.path.basename(name)
    print '\t', filename
    out=()
    for line in input:
        arr_input = line.split(",")
        feedback = arr_input[14]
        out.append(feedback)
    print out
```

Comment: And what have you tried doing? Have you looked at the [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method?

Comment: no!I've tried append! which I dont know if it makes sense!

Comment: Well what happens when you run this code? What is your output?

Comment: I get :
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: So that should tell you that you have declared `out` as the wrong type. The simple fix for that would be to change `out=()` to `out = []`. And then you can change `print out` to e.g.: `print ' '.join(out)`

Comment: worked... Thanks @UnholySheep